# Rsync to Amazon Ec2 Instance

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, rsync

I have an EC2 instance running and I am able to SSH into it.

However, when I try to rsync, it gives me the error Permission denied (publickey).

The command I'm using is:

```
rsync -avL --progress -e ssh -i ~/mykeypair.pem ~/Sites/my_site/* root@ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html/
```

I also tried

```
rsync -avz ~/Sites/mysite/* -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" root@ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html/
```

Thanks,

Comment: How are you SSHing into it?

Comment: Your second version is mostly right, except you are using the wrong key. You may also need to move the source path after the ssh command.

Comment: similar Q !  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821477/mac-to-ec2-git-rsync-wth

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I just received that same error. I had been consistently able to ssh with:

```
ssh -i ~/path/mykeypair.pem \
ubuntu@ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

But when using the longer **rsync** construction, it seemed to cause errors. I ended up encasing the ssh statement in quotations and using the full path to the key. In your example:

```
rsync -avL --progress -e "ssh -i /path/to/mykeypair.pem" \
       ~/Sites/my_site/* \ 
       root@ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html/
```

That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: if you had trouble with the verbosity of the cmd you can give a try to [aws-upload](https://github.com/borracciaBlu/aws-upload).

Comment: If you want hidden files to transfer as well, remove * from the source path: `rsync -va  -e "ssh -i /path/to/key.pem" /source/path/ ubuntu@ec2-nn-nnn-nnn-nnn.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/destination/path/`

Answer (score 19):

## use `rsync` to copy files between servers

copy file from local machine to server

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /path/to/key.pem" /path/to/file.txt  <username>@<ip/domain>:/path/to/directory/
```

copy file from server to local machine

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /path/to/key.pem" <username>@<ip/domain>:/path/to/directory/file.txt  /path/to/directory/
```

> note: use command with `sudo` if you are not a root user

Answer (score 17):

Below is what I used and it worked.  Source was ec2 and target was home machine.

```
 sudo rsync  -azvv -e "ssh -i /home/ubuntu/key-to-ec2.pem" ec2-user@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:/home/ec2-user/source/ /home/ubuntu/target/
```

Comment: Potentially dangerous. Erased a day's work at destination if you didn't understand what it means as it overwrites by whether files have differences.

Answer (score 12):

After suffering a little bit, I believe this will help:

I am using the below command and it has worked without problems:

```
rsync -av --progress -e ssh /folder1/folder2/* root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/folder1/folder2
```

**First consideration:**

Use the --rsync-path

I prefer in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

RSYNC = /usr/bin/rsync

$RSYNC [options] [source] [destination]
```

**Second consideration:**

Create a publick key by command below for communication between the servers in question. She will not be the same as provided by Amazon.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Do not forget to enable permission on the target server in /etc/ssh/sshd_config (UBUNTU and CENTOS).

[Sync files from one EC2 instance to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963740/sync-files-from-one-ec2-instance-to-another)

http://ask-leo.com/how_can_i_automate_an_sftp_transfer_between_two_servers.html

Use -v option for verbose and better identify errors.

**Third Consideration**

If both servers are on EC2 make a restraint by security group

In the security group Server Destination:

inbound:
Source / TCP port
22 / IP Security (or group name) of the source server

Comment: thanks for providing the second solution. you are a savior! the ask-leo site is a good resource for those trying to move files between 2 servers

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
nohup rsync -zravu --partial --progress  -e "ssh -i xxxx.pem" ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx:/mnt/data   /mnt2/ &
```