# cannot rsync between two ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, rsync

Is there a way to rsync between two ec2 instances? I found this [Rsync to Amazon Ec2 Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843195/rsync-to-amazon-ec2-instance) but its from local to an ec2 instance. Here is the command

```
rsync -av --progress data/* root@ipaddress:(path to folder)
```

And the error

```
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem. What's preventing you from just using `rsync`? Do you get an error? Do you not know how to configure the firewalls? What's the actual issue?

Comment: where you are running rsync from ? also which 2 hosts are involved in rsyncing? you need to provide more specific details.