# getting error to tranfer files from local to AWS ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ssh, rsync

Already SSH with the help of putty into AWS EC2 instance, Now, using rsync with the following command.I am using Windows 10.

```
rsync -av /Users/Lenovo/Desktop/dir1/* ec2-user@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/file
```

**file** is a directory which is created in the ec2 instance on Remote.

Followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843195/rsync-to-amazon-ec2-instance) but not able to resolve.

```
Permission denied (publickey).
    rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
    rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Comment: You are not passing the private key.

Comment: I am using this command  `rsync -rave "ssh -i Users/Lenovo/Desktop/SSH/rs.pem" Users/Lenovo/Desktop/dir1/* ec2-user@xx.xxx.xxx.x:/file`

Comment: still the same error I am getting