# How to put python script in AWS?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, machine-learning

I want to place my python machine learning code in AWS. Can someone please help me with the procedure. Thank you.
Python script is in .py format.

Comment: Not much information here, but read up on https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many options available:

- You can start your script using EC2's [User Data feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)
- You can use [`rsync` your script to the EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843195/rsync-to-amazon-ec2-instance) and run it over SSH
- You can build a Docker container in which you would include your script and [run a task in ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/start_task_at_launch.html)
- If your script takes less than 15 minutes to execute, you can [run it in a Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/get-started-create-function.html)